# Are there examples of 'anti-patterns' being used effectively?

Tags: design-patterns, design

I am sure many of us have come across a situation when we have been asked to design or implement something that appears to be an 'anti-pattern', that is to say, something that doesn't seem to follow good design guidelines/best practices. However, I think that the concept of an 'anti-pattern' when it is just a design pattern used inappropriately would suggest to be that there may be instances when it is appropriate to use these patterns. Perhaps we are only constrained by our current user interface design paradigms and concepts, and we are not pushing the boundary far enough so we seem to have patterns and anti-patterns when in fact the anti-patterns may just be waiting for innovative people to find user interface designs that will work for them.

The question I have is this: Have you ever found a suitable situation to use what would normally be considered an 'anti-pattern'? And was this within a traditional/current user interface design or something that is a little bit more innovative and cutting edge?